Change ReShaper shortcut
How can the ReSharper – User use  Ctrl+E Ctrl+U to uncomment the current line in C# code?
I have tired to change the short cut in Visual Studio and could not change the shortcut for "Edit.Uncomment". I am expecting that some one has find the solution and let me know, how I can use Ctrl+E Ctrl+U to uncomment the current line of C# code in Visual Studio.

See Comment and uncomment code documentation which indicates the settings to change shortcuts for comment and uncommenting code.
